# kotlin, is it ok to call null.also{}

Tags: generics, kotlin, nullable

There is code like:

```
result.also{......}
```

but the `result` might be null and the compiler does not complain,  it is same as

```
null.also{...}
```

is it ok to call `also{}`  on `null`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is. As the function definition tells you...

```
inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T (source)
```

...`T` does not define any upper bound and may therefore be used with any, *nullable* and *non-nullable*, type (`<T>` is the same as `<T: Any?>`).

If you're afraid about NullPointerExceptions, you don't need to be. The `also` function simply invokes the `block` with its receiver, `null` in your case, before again returning the receiver. For example, the following is legit:

```
 //returns null and _also_ prints "null"
return null.also { println(it) }
```